# TYPO3: How to avoid or fix truncated filenames in XML export?

Tags: xml, export, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I am having problems getting a propper xml-export from the export-module in TYPO3.

TYPO3-Version = 7.6.15

**Action:**

- Select a page from the pageTree -> context menu -> Export to .t3d
- Export Settings:

  - All tables
  - Save files in extra folder beside the export file:...
  - File format = XML

**Result:**

The XML file gets created in the target folder (fileadmin/user_upload/*temp*/importexport/)

**Problem:**

The filenames in this xml get truncated after 43characters.

**Excerpt of the xml:**

```
<rec index="9705" type="array">
  <uid>9705</uid>
  <pid>423</pid>
  <title>Bikeservice-text-and-image-bikeguidine.j...</title>
  <size>929</size>
  <relations index="rels" type="array">
    <element index="sys_file:3252" type="array">
      <id>3252</id>
      <table>sys_file</table>
    </element>
  </relations>
  <softrefs type="array"></softrefs>
</rec>
```

**Question**

Has anyone stumbled upon this problem or found a solution?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: That sounds more like a bug to me.

Comment: Seems so.... I saw in the export-module (./sysext/impexp/Classes/Export.php) that the title is truncated after 40 Characters. Will try to contact a core developer about that issue.

Comment: Please create a bug at https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues

Comment: Bug created: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/79598

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to remove the tables `sys_file` from static relations, because all data of static relations is excluded during export.